# How I can split string into columns and rows in Oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have following string(its a one string in a column) -

```
<09/27/2014 15:04:35:Registered:No update
<09/27/14 15:55:45:Work Completed:No update>
<09/29/2014 12:42:02:Informed:No update>>
<09/30/2014 11:18:40:Acknowledge:No update>>>
<09/30/2014 11:18:56:Travel Start:No update>>>>
<09/30/2014 11:19:06:Travel End:No update>>>>>
<09/30/2014 11:19:18:Work Commenced:No update>>>>>>
<09/30/2014 11:19:29:Fault Rectified:No update>>>>>>>
<09/30/2014 11:19:40:Work Completed:done>
```

I want to show the following string into multiple columns with separate rows as -

```
Date                  Status          Description
09/27/2014 15:04:35   Registered      No update
09/27/2014 15:55:45   Work Completed  No update
```

and so on..

How I can use regexp for <, >, space and colon to split single column into multiple column and rows.

**EDIT-**

```
    <09/27/2014 15:04:35:Registered:No update
    <09/27/14 15:55:45:Work Completed:No update>
    <09/29/2014 12:42:02:Informed:No update>>
```

above string can have 1 row or 2 row or multiple row like, its not fixed

Comment: you have eight newlines in the string?  Why to you have so many ">" at the end of lines? are they arbitrary?

Comment: please see the edit and for each line > will increase by one..

Answer (score 1):

Since it a single row, you need to first [**split the string into multiple rows**](https://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/) using new line character as delimiter.

And then, you could do it using simple **SUBSTR** and **INSTR**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT '<09/27/2014 15:04:35:Registered:No update
  3  <09/27/2014 15:55:45:WORK Completed:No update>
  4  <09/29/2014 12:42:02:Informed:No update>>
  5  <09/30/2014 11:18:40:Acknowledge:No update>>>
  6  <09/30/2014 11:18:56:Travel Start:No update>>>>
  7  <09/30/2014 11:19:06:Travel END:No update>>>>>
  8  <09/30/2014 11:19:18:Work Commenced:No update>>>>>>
  9  <09/30/2014 11:19:29:Fault Rectified:No update>>>>>>>
 10  <09/30/2014 11:19:40:Work Completed:done>' str FROM dual
 11  )
 12  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
 13  SELECT substr(str, 2, instr(str, ':', 1, 3) -2) col1,
 14         substr(str, instr(str, ':', 1, 3) +1, instr(str, ':', 1, 4)
 15            - instr(str, ':', 1, 3) -1) col2,
 16         REPLACE(substr(str, instr(str, ':', 1, 4) +1), '>', '') col3
 17  FROM(
 18       SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^
 19  ]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
 20       FROM sample_data
 21       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(str, chr(10))+1 );

COL1                 COL2            COL3
-------------------- --------------- ----------
09/27/2014 15:04:35  Registered      No update
09/27/2014 15:55:45  WORK Completed  No update
09/29/2014 12:42:02  Informed        No update
09/30/2014 11:18:40  Acknowledge     No update
09/30/2014 11:18:56  Travel Start    No update
09/30/2014 11:19:06  Travel END      No update
09/30/2014 11:19:18  Work Commenced  No update
09/30/2014 11:19:29  Fault Rectified No update
09/30/2014 11:19:40  Work Completed  done

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: The sample data should be one string. One row. So, it is needed a split into lines before doing what you've done.

Comment: good hint for me, not giving me exact result, but I can make adjust from here. Once done will mark it answered. Thnx